# "A diamond baseball bat would be very easy to break compared to a wood baseball bat." Is this true? If so, why?

Tags: collision, material-science, stress-strain, diamond

In a [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/687343/), someone mentioned that a diamond baseball bat would be very easy to break compared to a wood baseball bat. Is this true?

If I could create a baseball bat that is made out of 100% pure, solid diamond without any defects -- would it really be easier to break than wood? If so, why?

Comment: Diamond might be hard in a scratch test but is not very tough against shattering and impact.

Comment: Diamond is a brittle material - all it takes is one flaw for it to shatter off a piece (as is done regularly by folks making diamond jewelry). Wood is a composite material evolved to withstand and bounce back from lots of force and deformation from wind forces.

Comment: The answers up to now all rely on the ease of shattering of a diamond: While i agree that a wooden baseball bat striking a ceramic tiled wall might survive, while the diamond bat would shatter, or hitting both bats ina vise with a steel hammer would see the wooden bat come out better,

 a normal usage of the bat, i.e using human hands to swing it, impacting a ~50m/s baseball, might not be enough to shatter the diamond. The head of the bat would mass about 3-4 times as much (given the same geometry as a wooden bat, diamond being 3-4 times more dense;) rules for bats: <2.61 in dia, <42 in len

Comment: I.e "ease of breakage" is not a good quality - is it 'easier' to drive a 10-ton lorry over it while suspended on either end (wood would lose) or is it easier to hit it with a metal hammer while gripped in a vice (diamond would lose)?  --- As the Q is about a baseball bat, my take would be to look at it in 'natural use', i.e. having it gripped in a human hand (elastic) while hitting increasingly fast balls  - and here my guess is wood would lose. Also 'bat' is loosely defined: no lower limit on weight (or upper for that matter), it usually is a natural outcome of the mechanical limits of wood.

Comment: @bukwyrm A wooden baseball bat, swung by human hands against a regulation baseball ***will not shatter***, so it is a bit of an asinine requirement. You could break it, maybe, although that usually requires impact wit the ground, a concrete pillar, or an annoying fan's cranium. Normal use will never *shatter* a baseball bat, so it's a bit silly to compare the shatterability of wood vs. diamond in that non-event scenario.

Comment: @PcMan : i was going for ever increasing velocity of the ball (with the bat-break-point being the measure), while keeping the other requirements as near to a usually used bat as possible. You could of course also keep the ball at human speeds and make the hands harder, or the bat thinner, or the ball harder, ... etc. - until either the wood or diamond bat shatters -  my comment's goal was meant to solve the inherent problem with asking for the 'breakability' of something. Sorry if it was a bit hard to read.

Comment: @PcMan https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51V7VBk3r8I

Comment: @PcMan Wooden baseball bats swung by human hands at a regulation baseball do break, and sometimes even shatter (break into multiple pieces). Broken bats are a regular occurrence in Major League Baseball, with about one bat being broken per game.

Comment: @DavidHammen Break and Shatter are two different words.

Comment: @PcMan Some wooden baseball bats do shatter, break into multiple pieces of varying size.

Comment: The cleavage planes in diamond (vs. other allotropes) are ultimately why the crystal cannot withstand forces in certain directions.

Comment: All of the existing answers so far seem very hand-wavy and non-quantitative, though I'm sure they're correct about the reasoning involved.  Is there a quantitative argument that shows how much force (or, about how fast a baseball would have to be thrown) is required to break a wooden vs. diamond bat?  I'm sure it's complicated by the direction of impact, for both wood (as any ball player knows) and diamond (as apparently gem cutters know).

Comment: @KenWilliams Well seeing as how I doubt you'll find a diamond baseball bat the best you'll probably find are strain-stress curves. Because it's not so much about force as the energy that needs to be dissipated over some time or distance, which then results in force. Or tap a diamond with a hammer vs a piece of wood.

Comment: Wood is flexible. Diamond is not.

Consider steel as compared to either cast or wrought iron…

Answer (score 11):

Stronger materials are generally more brittle. In stronger materials, locations of stress concentration tend to stay sharp instead of blunting. Specifically, the high strength limits the size of the so-called plastic zone at crack tips, which would otherwise absorb energy.

In brief, Nature says: If I can’t dissipate deformation energy within the material (by generating dislocations, for example), then, well, I’ll put that energy toward creating new surfaces. And so the material shatters.

Comment: The term "stronger" is not typically the one that gets used for this property, in material science "harder" is more specific to what you mean here

Comment: Strength is the appropriate term. I’m referring broadly to resistance to permanent deformation. Hardness could connote a surface property, which is not the intended meaning.

Comment: I don't see how it necessarily follows that the energy _must_ be dissipated as dislocations or fracture. What prevents the energy from just being dissipated as heat?

Comment: Some energy is dissipated as heat. But phenomenologically, we do observe shattering in some circumstances. Thus, energy is sometimes expended to create new surfaces.

Answer (score 10):

Let's compare the following three cases:
-a steel rod
-a glass rod
-a diamond rod

For the steel let's use the type of steel that is used for the bar of a [barbell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbell)

When the weighlifter lifts the barbell you see that the bar flexes a little.

A glass rod will bend much less than a steel rod. When a glass rod is subjected to a bending force then at one side, at the very surface, there will be a peak tensile load.

Compare that to the steel rod. As the steel rod is subjected to a bending force the surface at one side will be under the most tensile load, but the steel at that very highest tensile load spot can elongate. The effect of that localized elongation is that the load is distributed over a larger volume of steel. That *distribution* is key.

In the case of the glass rod:
The glass is extremely *rigid*. Because of that rigidity I expect that the glass will have almost no opportunity to spread the load. The load will tend to concentrate in one spot, and when that one spot fails the entire glass rod fails.

The diamond rod is even more rigid than the glass rod.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I've never heard of the take where being able to deflect more spreads the point load on the material.

Comment: Thin enough glass does flex.  In fact, it can be very flexible indeed (glass wool, optical fiber, ...).  Thicker glass can also bend, a lot, but at room temperature that has to be (very) slow to avoid breakage.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Erm.. when thin enough *any* material will undergo elastic deformation, escaping the plastic deformation that would lead to structural failure. That is the reason why steel cables for cranes etc. are *stranded* cables. The stranded/twined cable can bend way more than a rod of the same diameter (and type of steel) can, without being compromised. So it's not clear why you added that 'thin enough' comment: it only states the glaringly obvious.

Comment: Glass isn't a crystalline solid, so it isn't as helpful a comparison as might be meant

Comment: @Cleonis It's also much easier to create and transport steel cable rather than a giant steel rod. The twisting of the cables can even occur at the construction site rather than needing to be transported in its final state. Even if it was structurally viable imagine transporting the main cables of the Golden Gate Bridge that are 7,659 feet long and three feet in diameter as a single rod, it would be nearly impossible

Answer (score 7):

There's three things of some relevance here.

1. The first is **tensile strength** and **compressive strength** which is how much force it takes to
   break something. High tensile strength makes a material **strong**: A material that takes a lot of force to break.
2. Then there is **stiffness** which is how much force it takes to achieve
   a particular amount of deflection in something.
3. With #2 and #3, you get the deflection required to break something. I don't know of a term for this so I will just call it the **ultimate deflection** in this post.

Then there is **hardness** which (to me at least) is difficult to quantify. One definition is possibly the resistance to local deformation which makes it abrasion resistant and difficult to scratch. It might sound like stiffness, but it's not.

It is well known diamonds are hard. However, in terms of breaking something, hardness is not involved.

You can get materials with enormous amounts of ultimate deflection. That is, they can deflect a great deal without breaking; Like a rubber band. But obviously, a rubber band has low stiffness because it does not take a lot of force to achieve any particular deflection. Nor does it have very high strength because it does not take a lot of force to break.

Then you have materials like steel which have high strength and stiffness. But, for how much force it takes to bend to break, steel can deflect quite a lot before actually breaking. That makes it **tough** and able to absorb lots of energy which is different than being able to absorb a lot of force.

Then you have materials like diamond which are even more stiff than steel and take even more force to achieve a particular deflection, but cannot deflect all that much before breaking. It is possible for the reduced ultimate deflection to outweigh stiffness to result in a material with lower breaking strength.

Then you have carbon fiber which takes even more force to break than steel and takes even more force to achieve a particular deflection than steel. Yet, the deflection it breaks at is less than steel. So it is stronger than steel, yet comparatively brittle and less able to absorb large amounts of energy. But still enough toughness to be useful for structural purposes.

Some scenarios are forced limited such as slowly applying force like with diamond anvils. In that case, as long as you load up the material slowly, ensuring to never exceed the strength it can ultimately support a lot more force than a comparable material

However, other scenarios are energy limited, such as impacts. An impact involves changes in momentum and rapid accelerations (or decelerations if you will) and aren't limited by force as much as they are limited by the kinetic energy involved which needs to be dissipated. These scenarios can easily generate forces higher than what can be supported by a material with high strength that deflect enough to absorb the energy. Being able to deflect spreads out the deceleration over time which reduces the peak forces involved in the collisions.

Comment: Where you wrote " a rubber band has stiffness" I think you meant "a rubber band has negligible stiffness".

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes. Corrected.